# HTML form submit to unexpected URL

Tags: html, forms, html-formhandler

I had facing a problem and found out a hot fix for it. But i do not know how the workflow of submit HTML form and i want to know why it happens. Following is my situation:
if i have a IMG wih src attribute value is undefined placed outside all of the forms in my website. When i click button to submit a form. It will get undefined value in src attribute of img appended to action value attribute of the form submitting. For e.g:

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="undefined">
<form action="http://sample.com/page/" method="POST">
   <input name="txt" type="hidden" value="abc" />
   <input name="num" type="hidden" value="123" />
   <label class="lbl">Enter your code: </label>
   <input name="input" type="text" />
   <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

The result after i click submit the form is 404 page not found, because i found out my action value of the form is appended with undefined value "http://sample.com/page/undefined". What happen here ? i am trying figure it out why.

Comment: You probably have some fancy JS messing with your DOM, to verify disable JavaScript in your browser and click the submit button. Anyway, nothing wrong in the code, and no way to know what is wrong

Comment: thank for you comment, i will try this